# How does swagger placeholders work?

Tags: express, yaml, swagger

​I have joined a project which uses Swagger. I see they have​​ used this kind of placeholders in the `Swagger.yaml` :

```
  MYKey: &CONST_MY_KEY ""
```

How does this work and where do I define `CONST_MY_KEY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define `CONST_MY_KEY` anywhere, the `&` introduces this as an anchor for the object `""`. You can reuse this in a later stage of a YAML file by using `*` to specify an alias: `*CONST_MY_KEY`.

The *primary* reason for anchors and aliases is **not** to duplicate content as @smartcaveman's answer indicates. It is to [represent a node in multiple locations in the representation graph](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765878).

Without this feature even the following simple Python construct could not be dumped:

```
data = dict(a=1)
data['b'] = data
```

if you dump the above:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

you'll get:

```
&id001
a: 1
b: *id001
```

Depending on the language you use and its YAML parser, using an anchor on a scalar, might only be useful for not having to repeat the value later on, without the advantage you get with collections (mappings, sequences) that they actually refer to the same object. Again in Python, the loading of scalars by the more popular parsers is done in separate entities:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a: &CONST_MY_KEY ""
b: *CONST_MY_KEY
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
print('a {a!r}'.format(**data))
print('b {b!r}'.format(**data))
data['a'] = 'hello'
print('a {a!r}'.format(**data))
print('b {b!r}'.format(**data))
```

gives you:

```
a ''
b ''
a 'hello'
b ''
```

Note that the value of `data['b']` doesn't change because (in most parsers) scalars are not constructed as referenced objects.

If you do that with the original example:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
&id001
b: *id001
a: 1
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
print('a {a!r}'.format(**data))
data['b']['a'] = 2
print('a {a!r}'.format(**data))
```

Because `data['a']` and `data['b']['a']` actually are the same object, and changing one changes the other.

The usage of `<<: *name` is a non-standard YAML extension. It expects `&name` to be an anchor on a mapping, for which the key-value pairs are added to the mapping the alias is used upon.

Comment: What about `MYKey`?

Comment: @fastcodejava: `MYKey` is a normal scalar, function as a a key for the value `""`. It is not necessary to define the anchor `CONST_MY_KEY`, but if you want to have multiple anchors defined, you need to have a mapping (or a sequence) as a collection to hold them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a YAML construct known as an anchor and is not specific to swagger.

The code you wrote actually defines the anchor `CONST_MY_KEY` as an empty string.  The `&`-prefix indicates that you are defining it.  If you wanted to reuse this anchor later in the document you would reference it using a `*`-prefix instead like `*CONST_MY_KEY`.

Below is an explanatory excerpt from https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/ :

```
# YAML also has a handy feature called 'anchors', which let you easily duplicate
# content across your document. Both of these keys will have the same value:
anchored_content: &anchor_name This string will appear as the value of two keys.
other_anchor: *anchor_name

# Anchors can be used to duplicate/inherit properties
base: &base
    name: Everyone has same name

foo: &foo
  <<: *base
  age: 10

bar: &bar
  <<: *base
  age: 20
```

Comment: The merge extension you quote is an extension implemented in some YAML parsers only, and not part of the YAML standard (although the definition is done by the people who wrote the standard). Using the same name in a mapping for a key and the anchor for the corresponding value (as your example does consistently) often confuses people to think there is some relationship, a **good** example always uses different scalars for those entities.